# Youtube search autocomplete not working with Framework 7

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete, youtube, html-framework-7

I am trying to use Framework 7 autocomplete feature with youtube search API v3. I had used search api for autocomplete using Jquery UI. Framework 7 has also Ajax autocomplete feature. But my code is not working with Framework 7.

Here is my youtube search autocomplete js code for jquery UI, that works 100% and shows up video search suggestion on text input

```
//code for auto complete using jquery UI works perfect
 jQuery( "#vid-search" ).autocomplete({
          source: function( request, response ) {
            //console.log(request.term);
            var sqValue = [];
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=yt&client=youtube&hjson=t&cp=1",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: jQuery.extend({
                    q: request.term
                }, {  }),
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data[1]);
                    obj = data[1];
                    jQuery.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
                        sqValue.push(value[0]);
                    });
                    response( sqValue);
                }
            });
          },
          select: function( event, ui ) {
            setTimeout( function () { 
                youtubeApiCall();
            }, 300);
          }
        });
```

And here is my youtube search autocomplete code with framework 7, Doest show up video search suggestions on text inpute..

```
var autocompleteDropdownAjax = myApp.autocomplete({
input: '#autocomplete-dropdown-ajax',
openIn: 'dropdown',
preloader: true, //enable preloader
valueProperty: 'id', //object's "value" property name
textProperty: 'name', //object's "text" property name
limit: 20, //limit to 20 results
dropdownPlaceholderText: 'Try "JavaScript"',
expandInput: true, // expand input
source: function (autocomplete, query, request, response, render) {
    var results = [];
    if (query.length === 0) {
        render(sqValue);
        return;
    }
    // Show Preloader
    autocomplete.showPreloader();
    // Do Ajax request to Autocomplete data
    $$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
                url: "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=yt&client=youtube&hjson=t&cp=1",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: jQuery.extend({
                    q: request.term
                }, {  }),
        success: function (data) {
            // Find matched items
            console.log(data[1]);
                    obj = data[1];
                    jQuery.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
                        sqValue.push(value[0]);
                    });
                    response( sqValue);
            // Hide Preoloader
            autocomplete.hidePreloader();
            // Render items by passing array with result items
            render(sqValue);
        }

    });
},
select: function( event, ui ) {
            setTimeout( function () { 
                youtubeApiCall();
            }, 300);
          }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the jSon result should be in a special format, the result rendered by the API looks like:

```
["funn",["funny vines","funny videos 2016","funny videos","funny","funnel vision","funny cat videos","funny fails","funny pranks","funny cats","funny songs"]]
```

First parent array has the query you typed, second child array has the result array, you must push the child array to the result.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
    results.push(data[1][i])
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Full code:

```
var autocompleteDropdownAjax = myApp.autocomplete({
  input: '#autocomplete-dropdown-ajax',
  openIn: 'dropdown',
  preloader: true, //enable preloader
  valueProperty: 'value', //object's "value" property name
  textProperty: 'text', //object's "text" property name
  limit: 20, //limit to 20 results
  dropdownPlaceholderText: 'Search Youtube',
  expandInput: true, // expand input
  source: function(autocomplete, query, render) {
    var results = [];
    var returned = [];
    if (query.length === 0) {
      render(results);
      return;
    }
    // Show Preloader
    autocomplete.showPreloader();
    // Do Ajax request to Autocomplete data
    $$.ajax({
      url: 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt',
      method: 'GET',
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'json',
      //send "query" to server. Useful in case you generate response dynamically
      data: {
        q: query
      },
      success: function(data) {
        // Find matched items
        for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
            results.push(data[1][i])
        }

        // Hide Preoloader
        autocomplete.hidePreloader();
        // Render items by passing array with result items
        render(results);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Its not working.. Here is what I tried according to your answer:
[https://codepen.io/gourabxz/pen/PbQJQq](https://codepen.io/gourabxz/pen/PbQJQq)

Comment: If you check the error console: `Blocked loading mixed active content `, it is because codepen is using HTTPS and the file you are calling is on an HTTP link, now after changing the json link to HTTPS you will get another common security error message: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked` which is another easy to fix problem, but you will need a custom hosted php file to handle the request, live working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoMXEz

Comment: The php file content i used:
`<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
echo file_get_contents("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&ds=yt&q=" . urlencode($_REQUEST['q']));
?>`

Comment: PLEASE NOTE: That was a temporary file i'm using to run the example, it might not work later, I will remove it, but i just posted the file content in the previous comment.

Comment: Thank you for your help.. Now its working... Bt can I ask:  before I was having problem with framework 7 ajax autocomplete, I had used jquery UI auto complete feature. As I have mentioned in my question, the jquery UI code was working and it was showing youtube search suggestions. Bt I didnt used any php file. Then how my jquery ui code was working with out having any error. You can take a look what jquery ui auto complete code i used in my question above. Thank you :)

Comment: Framework7 has a separated library for making ajax calls, they might be forgot something, I added jQuery library to your script and changed F7 method to that YouTube autocomplete method, and now it is working without the php file, check it out: https://codepen.io/tinyCoder/pen/WoMXEz

Comment: Haha.. Thank you so much. You are awesome.  :D